# white spaces on both side of my website on iphone7 . I used overflow x hidden but it causing onother problem

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I see that I have white spaces on both side of my website (I use bootstrap4)

on iphone 7.
I searched in google for solution so I saw in stackoverflow forum this code as solution :

after inserting this code in media query :

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
    
    .site-header  {
        background-color:grey;
    }
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}
```

when I resize my website to 500 pixels the window of my website is becoming very smal with under it white space. and when I open my website on iphone 7 I see only the header and the content is white space without any text (empty).
my url is :http://webdesignleren.com/
what it is the wrong here?
thanks
johan

Answer (score 0):

the content of your page is not visible because all the content is placed inside the element "site-header", which has a fixed height of 80px. Maybe you forgot to close that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was forgot to close site header.
but the problem is not solved untill I add:

```
html,body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
}
```